# How to created a grouped and stacked bar chart in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a combination grouped and stacked by chart in R using ggplot2.  I was able to create the basic chart using the code below, however its still not where I want to be.  I technically want 2 items in the x axis.  Right now it is displaying each of the types for each period.  What I would like is to have each `type` combination as a separate bar graph.  For example the `R.12` and the `R.3` types would be separate bar graphs side by side for each period (while keeping the `group` in the facet_grid).  As it is now all of the `R.12` and `R.3` values are stacked as one graph.  Hope this makes sense.  Thanks for any help.

```
library(ggplot2)
group <-c("group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2","group2")
period <-c("201912","201912","201912","201912","201911","201911","201911","201911","201910","201910","201910","201910","201912","201912","201912","201912","201911","201911","201911","201911","201910","201910","201910","201910")
type <- c("R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out","R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out","R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out","R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out","R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out","R.12_In","R.12_Out","R.3_In","R.3_Out")
amount <- c(100,20,50,5,95,25,50,7,97.5,27.5,52.5,9.5,105,25,55,10,100,30,55,12,98.5,28.5,53.5,10.5)

df <- data.frame(group,period, type, amount)

df<- with(df, df[order(period, type, amount),])

ggplot(df, aes(fill= type, y = amount, x= period)) +
  geom_bar( stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(acurracy=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue4", "#999999", "darkorange","lightslategray" )) +
  theme_minimal()+
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_grid(~group)
```

Comment: Am I correct to understand that you want to have 4 facets:  Group1 R3, Group1 R12, Group2 R3, and Group2 R12?  If that's the case, you should be spearating out your "type" as two separate columns:  "Type" (R2 or R12) and "IO" (In or Out).  Then you can facet on Type and get the four plots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another variation, using the "group" option in the aes definition:

```
df <- data.frame(group, period, type, amount) 

#Create the major grouping variable
df$majortype<-sub("_.+$", "", df$type) 

df<- with(df, df[order(period, type, amount),])

ggplot(df, aes(fill= type, y = amount, x= period, group=majortype)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(acurracy=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue4", "#999999", "darkorange","lightslategray" )) +
  theme_minimal()+
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_grid(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: This is it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand correctly. Something like that:

```
df$type2 <- ifelse(grepl("R\\.12", type), "R.12", "R.3")

ggplot(df, aes(fill= type, y = amount, x= period)) +
  geom_bar( stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(acurracy=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue4", "#999999", "darkorange","lightslategray" )) +
  theme_minimal()+
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_grid(~group + type2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I was trying to stack R.12_in with R.12_Out (same with R.3's)