# Making a grouped stacked barchart over different dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

**Background**: I want to create the following stacked barchart in R, which looks something like this:
[image]

**Data**: The data which I have consist of bonds with different coupon rates. Inside these bonds there exist three debtor classes: "Small, medium and large loans". On a given date each of these bonds have different nominal values which consist of the sum of the debtor classes inside the bond. What I want to plot is how the coupon bond distribution changes over time inside these loan size classes (like the picture shows).

**Reproducible code** First of all, I can only provide a snippet of the code. The real data frame itself is just too big to lay out here. However, Ill try and show what I have done myself and show how I fail.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df = structure(list(Dato = c("04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
                             "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
                             "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "07-23", 
                             "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
                             "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
                             "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
                             "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
                             "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23"
), Fondskode = c("DK0002027036", "DK0002027036", "DK0004616950", 
                 "DK0004616950", "DK0004616950", "DK0007200976", "DK0009410425", 
                 "DK0009410425", "DK0009410425", "DK0009524431", "DK0009524431", 
                 "DK0009524431", "DK0009529315", "DK0009529315", "DK0009529315", 
                 "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0002027036", 
                 "DK0002027036", "DK0004616950", "DK0004616950", "DK0004616950", 
                 "DK0007200976", "DK0009410425", "DK0009410425", "DK0009410425", 
                 "DK0009524431", "DK0009524431", "DK0009524431", "DK0009529315", 
                 "DK0009529315", "DK0009529315", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
                 "DK0009539116", "DK0002027036", "DK0002027036", "DK0004616950", 
                 "DK0004616950", "DK0004616950", "DK0007200976", "DK0009410425", 
                 "DK0009410425", "DK0009410425", "DK0009524431", "DK0009524431", 
                 "DK0009524431", "DK0009529315", "DK0009529315", "DK0009529315", 
                 "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116"), KuponRente = c(3, 
                                                                                 3, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
                                                                                 3, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
                                                                                 3, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 4, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), 
DistributionNew = c("Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", 
                    "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", 
                    "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", 
                    "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", 
                    "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Medium Loans", 
                    "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", 
                    "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", 
                    "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", 
                    "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", 
                    "Small Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", 
                    "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", 
                    "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", 
                    "Small Loans", "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans", 
                    "Large Loans", "Medium Loans", "Small Loans"), TotalSumNominel = c(14871078, 
                                                                                       230519644, 124229666, 105950539, 191869576, 34229, 166832711, 
                                                                                       415771109, 75355256, 10450320996, 30789310193, 4276173735, 
                                                                                       4277192442, 2200535956, 1145694826, 727112293, 32524077976, 
                                                                                       6350025138, 14544895, 221211378, 133635759, 97870396, 188590028, 
                                                                                       26114, 166287052, 402943367, 78061232, 10294401373, 28473616784, 
                                                                                       4071460911, 4182694064, 2000153569, 1107766445, 1199628400, 
                                                                                       46958195327, 9033691732, 13221795, 212722212, 110535953, 
                                                                                       88797232, 185525718, 26114, 165736626, 388110231, 75004980, 
                                                                                       10188496496, 26486190527, 3893875368, 4094368265, 1832338499, 
                                                                                       1083867006, 1506440905, 54391483677, 10106559492)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                     "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -54L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                       Dato = c("04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
                                                                                                                                                                "04-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
                                                                                                                                                                "07-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
                                                                                                                                                                "10-23"), Fondskode = c("DK0002027036", "DK0004616950", "DK0007200976", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "DK0009410425", "DK0009524431", "DK0009529315", "DK0009539116", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "DK0002027036", "DK0004616950", "DK0007200976", "DK0009410425", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "DK0009524431", "DK0009529315", "DK0009539116", "DK0002027036", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "DK0004616950", "DK0007200976", "DK0009410425", "DK0009524431", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "DK0009529315", "DK0009539116"), KuponRente = c(3, -0.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        4, 6, 1, 1, 5, 3, -0.5, 4, 6, 1, 1, 5, 3, -0.5, 4, 6, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1, 5), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:5, 6L, 7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      16:18, 19:20, 21:23, 24L, 25:27, 28:30, 31:33, 34:36, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      37:38, 39:41, 42L, 43:45, 46:48, 49:51, 52:54), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ), row.names = c(NA, -21L), .drop = TRUE))
df_summarized <- df %>%
  group_by(Dato, DistributionNew) %>%
  mutate(
    TotalSumNominelPerDate = sum(TotalSumNominel, na.rm = TRUE),
    PercentageOfTotal = (TotalSumNominel / TotalSumNominelPerDate) * 100
  ) 




ggplot(df_summarized, aes(x = DistributionNew, y = PercentageOfTotal, fill = factor(KuponRente))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), aes(group = interaction(DistributionNew, Dato))) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "KuponRente") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Stacked Bar Chart by DistributionNew for each Date",
       x = "DistributionNew",
       y = "Percentage of Total",
       fill = "KuponRente") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0.5, 0.5)))
```

Where the reproducible code yields this graph:
[image]

Which I really dont get. I cant seem to stack them together and let each % of the different "KuponRente" fill out the stacked bar up to 100%. I must do something really wrong, however I cant figure out how.

Below I have also attached the image, which i generate with the full data set (and not only the snippet which i provided):
[image]

**My question in a nutshell:** How do I get ggplot to stack my data correctly according to my little drawing?

Comment: grouped stacked charts in ggplot2 are a little trickier, since you are asking for two different position adjustments: 1) horizontal dodging between Dato groups, as well as 2) stacking among KuponRente values. Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191011/how-to-created-a-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart-in-r-with-ggplot2. One easy solution might be to put DistributionNew in facets, x using Dato, and then use position_stack instead of dodge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't have a stacked and dodged barchart at the same time, i.e. with your code the bars are dodged but plotted on top of each other.

One option to get close to your desired result would be to use facetting, i.e. make a stacked barchart and facet by `DistributionNew`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df_summarized <- df %>%
  group_by(Dato, DistributionNew, KuponRente) %>%
  summarise(
    TotalSumNominel = sum(TotalSumNominel, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) |> 
  mutate(PercentageOfTotal = TotalSumNominel / sum(TotalSumNominel) * 100)

ggplot(df_summarized, aes(
  x = Dato, y = PercentageOfTotal,
  fill = factor(KuponRente)
)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "KuponRente") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0.5, 0.5)), position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~DistributionNew, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Stacked Bar Chart by DistributionNew for each Date",
    x = "DistributionNew",
    y = "Percentage of Total",
    fill = "KuponRente"
  )
```

[image]